# I want to have a bond with a baby dragon. Can I?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragons, background

I just started playing D&D 5e. I am playing an Ethereal Dwarf, Paladin level 2, and my background is Haunted One. With my background, I received a broken silver dragon pendant. My harrowing event is also "A monster slaughtered hundreds of my people but spared my life."

Now I have to still make my background which I was hoping would be related to my harrowing event and the rest like my Personality traits, Ideals, Bonds, and Flaws. I was hoping for my background to be like:

> I grew up in the clan of Ungart where one day I stumbled across a dragon egg. I picked it up and brought it back to my village where me and my brother, who was 78 at the time, would take care of it. Months past and the egg hatched. We decided to name it (Not decided yet). Years passed and the dragon grew little by little each year, we were so happy, until that one day. Roaring in the distance we realized that a silver dragon had found our town. We fought it but failed. Hundreds died. Me and my brother survived but what still gets me is that the dragon looked at us in anger and turned away like it didn't want to hurt us. I still do not know why to this day. Now I am off on my journey to bring justice to monsters who terrorize other people.

Can someone tell me if I can have a certain bond with the dragon or does this story really not work in game play?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Have you talked to your DM about this possible backstory yet?

Comment: He said that he thinks it is good and really there is no rule agianst it but, he isn't a prestige type DM to the game.

Comment: Considering silver dragons are LG, it is quite unlikely for one to slaughter an entire village with its (his? her?) own will. It could be under a potent spell, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## DM's choice

It is up to your DM what special features that your character might have from their background. There is nothing in the rules that specifically allows this, but no rule that prevents it. It mostly falls under the heading of "plot" and that is entirely the DM's domain.

I will note that silver dragons are normally lawful good so it would need to have a really good reason to attack a town and kill hundreds of people.

Comment: Ok I can change it up a little but thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As I discovered in my recent question, [players having dragons is fairly overpowered.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/160769/is-this-homebrew-dragon-rider-class-balanced-compared-to-the-other-official-clas)

However, depending on what lore you use, pseudodragons may or may not be baby dragons, but in the *Monster Manual* (p. 254), there is an option for [pseudodragons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-p#Pseudodragon) to bond with other creatures:

> #### Variant: Pseudodragon Familiar
>
> Some pseudodragons are willing to serve spellcasters as a familiar. Such pseudodragons have the following trait.
>
> ***Familiar.*** The pseudodragon can serve another creature as a familiar, forming a magic, telepathic bond with that willing companion. While the two are bonded, the companion can sense what the pseudodragon senses as long as they are within 1 mile of each other. While the pseudodragon is within 10 feet of its companion, the companion shares the pseudodragon’s Magic Resistance trait. At any time and for any reason, the pseudodragon can end its service as a familiar, ending the telepathic bond.

You can ask your DM about having one, or obtain one at third level as a Pact of the Chain Warlock.

Comment: Note that the "Variant: Familiar" sidebar in the MM has no interaction with the *find familiar* spell; it's intended for the DM to use with actual pseudodragons (or imps, or other creatures for which such a sidebar appears) that choose to form a contract with an NPC spellcaster. Even if the DM allows an actual pseudodragon to form such a contract with a PC, it does not interact with the spell at all. Related: [Why can't the “Variant: Imp Familiar” be found with the Find Familiar spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101217/33569)

Answer (score 3):

## You can have a bond about the dragon

The rules for Personal Characterisitcs (PHB, p123) state:

> Fleshing out your character's personality—the array of traits, mannerisms, habits, beliefs, and flaws that give a person a unique identity—will help you bring him or her to life as you play the game. Four categories of characteristics are presented here: personality traits, ideals, **bonds**, and flaws. [···]
>
> Each background presented later in this chapter includes suggested characteristics that you can use to spark your imagination. **You're not bound to those options**, but they're a good starting point.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Bonds
>
> Create one bond for your character. **Bonds represent a character's connections to people, places, and events in the world.** They tie you to things from your background. They might inspire you to heights of heroism, or lead you to act against your own best interests if they are threatened. They can work very much like ideals, driving a character's motivations and goals.
>
> Bonds might answer any of these questions: **Whom do you care most about?** To what place do you feel a special connection? What is your most treasured possession?
>
> Your bonds might be tied to your class, your background, your race, or **some other aspect of your character's history** or personality. You might also gain new bonds over the course of your adventures.

Given your backstory, it is entirely reasonable for you to have a bond about that dragon. Stuff like "[dragon's name] ows me a debt of blood", or "I can't rest until I ask [dragon's name] why it slaughtered my town".

A bond doesn't give you agency over the dragon's actions, but it represents your shared history with the dragon, which in turn influences how how your character and the dragon will behave upon meeting during the campaign.

Note that a backstory should fit within the setting of the campaign. Whether the backstory should accommodate the setting or the other way around is a decision that each table approaches differently.

For example, in a generic D&D setting, silver dragons are lawful good and wouldn't attack a town without a really aggravating reason. The setting might be altered to accomodate an evil silver dragon, that aggravating reason might exist even if you don't know of it, or you might just choose a different colored dragon.